# Vim search: how to factor in the white space during the search?

Tags: search, whitespace

Doing a search with `/` can be useful, however, it becomes harder to find things if the term you are searching for is a part of other words. I have a large text document with notes i've made about the BASH command language, and if i hit `/cat`, in reference to the cat command, it just takes me to some word with "cat" as a part of it, like `locate`.

During a search, is there a way to use the white space surrounding, preceding, or fallowing a term in order to find a word or sequence or characters? I've tried using double and single quotes with no luck. EOF ($) works, but that won't help find words in the middle of a document.

Comment: Try `/\<cat\>` and see `:help \<` and also `:help *`

Comment: Note that in a pattern `$` is end-of-line (EOL), not end-of-file (EOF). As a range, however, `$` is EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mattb proposes you could search for cat as a word:

```
/\<cat\>
```

The `\<` and `\>` token match the word boundaries.

Remark: If you have `cat` selected and hit `*` this what `Vim` will do.

But you can also do the same using the following pattern.

```
/\v<cat>
```

To limit the number of backslash to type, you can switch on the magic mode using the `\v` token.

In magic mode the special tokens like `<`, `>`, `+`, `(`, `)`, ... don't need to be escaped.

More information about the magic mode using: `help /magic`

Comment: those both work, yet you could explain what's happening "under the hood" in order to make the answer better.

Comment: @thinksinbinary see `:help \<`